# Why 'form close' event is not happening when a huge for loop is runnig in Delphi?

Tags: performance, delphi, delphi-xe2, pascal

I am trying out following code. However, if I click on form's close button while this code is running, nothing happens. How can I correct this? I need to close the form even when this loop is executing.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 9999999 do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('hi');
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you wrap the update of the memo like this: `Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate; for i := 0 to 9999999 do Memo1.Lines.Add('hi'); Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;`, then perhaps the need to abort the process is irrelevant.

Comment: The above comment by LU RD has too few upvotes. Please upvote it.

Comment: +1 for `LU RD`; an `Application.ProcessMessages()` call is usually a code-smell.

Comment: Solve the real problem by fixing the code so that it doesn't block the GUI thread. And doesn't call the infernal ProcessMessages.

Comment: Application.ProcessMessages will make your loop terribly slow. Better do something like this inc(Counter); if counter > 1000 then Application.ProcessMessages Counter:= 0;

Comment: Actually better: if counter > 1000 then Memo1.Update;  But this is lazy man's solution. I would do what David H says: move the slow code in a separated thread. You have to write WAY more than two lines of code and you need to deal with thread synchronization then, but IT IS the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have a look at what's going on inside `Application.ProcessMessages`.

When you close the main form, windows sends a `WM_QUIT` message to the program.  The relevant part of `TApplication.ProcessMessages` looks like this:

```
    if Msg.Message <> WM_QUIT then
    begin
      //skipped
    end
    else
    begin
{$IF DEFINED(CLR)}
      if Assigned(FOnShutDown) then FOnShutDown(self);
      DoneApplication;
{$IFEND}
      FTerminate := True;
    end;
```

I assume this is not a CLR program, so the only thing that happens at this point is setting `FTerminate := True` on `Application`.  This is reflected in the `Application.Terminated` property.

When the application shuts down, one of the things it does in order to shut down safely is wait for all threads to finish.  This code happens to be running in the main thread, but the principle would be the same in any thread: If you're doing a long-running task that might have to finish early, *you have to explicitly check for early termination.*

Knowing this, it's easy to figure out how to fix your code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 9999999 do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('hi');
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    if Application.Terminated then
      Break;
  end;
end;
```

Also, beware of using `Application.ProcessMessages` in the first place, as it will process all messages for the application.  For a simple idea of what might go wrong, try adding `IntToStr(i)` instead of `'hi'` to `Memo1.Lines`, knock a couple of orders of magnitude off the counter, and then click the button two or three times in rapid succession and watch the output...

Comment: Did you mean to say, using 'Application.ProcessMessages' is not good?

Comment: @jimsweb, see [`The Dark Side of Application.ProcessMessages in Delphi Applications`](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-processmessages-dark-side.htm). Every time you think it is needed, it's time to reconsider the implementation strategy.

Comment: @LURD This article was really useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Check for Apllication Terminated:

```
  for i := 0 to 9999999 do
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('hi');
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    if Application.Terminated then Exit;
  end;
```

Comment: perhaps better `...then Abort;` so that some potential outer loops (in caller subroutines) would be exited as well.

Comment: @Arioch'The, for a ButtonClick? In addition Abort would set an error condition for the process. I would rate Abort as a little bit too much.

Comment: Abort and exit have the same observable behaviour here

Comment: Never saw a code, where event handlers were called explicitly, as part of programs' behaviour ? :-D

Answer (score 1):

You need to run any tight loop in a thread. This will solve the problem.

**BUT** if you want to keep the code as it is, Application.ProcessMessages will make your loop terribly slow. So you need to run Application.ProcessMessages not so often:

```
  Counter:= 0; 
  for i := 0 to 9999999 do
  begin
    DoSomeStuff;

    { Prevent freeze }  
    inc(Counter); 
    if counter > 10000 then 
     begin 
       Counter:= 0;
       Application.ProcessMessages;
       if Application.Terminated then Exit;
      end; 
  end;
```